# How Tensorflow uses my gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

So I am training a NN in tensorflow and in the same time I am monitoring my GPU load.

[image: GPU Load]

From the screenshot I see that Tensorflow basically uses only the GPU memory, is this normal ? I thought they utilize all my cuda cores to perform some computations and etc.

Is there are someone who knows this stuff in detal ?

Thanks in advance!

Here comes the code ...

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

# ... some file reading here 

def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = features,
        y = labels,
        num_epochs = 1,
        shuffle = True,
        batch_size = batch_size)

def eval_input_fn(features, labels):
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = features,
        y = labels,
        num_epochs = 1,
        shuffle = True)

def pred_input_fn(features):
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = features,
        num_epochs = 1,
        shuffle = False)

model_dir = './DNN_Linear_Combined_Regressor'

file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(model_dir)

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor(
    model_dir = model_dir,
    linear_feature_columns = wide_columns,
    dnn_feature_columns = deep_columns,
    dnn_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001),
    dnn_hidden_units = [64,64,64,8], 
    batch_norm = True,
    dnn_dropout = 0.1
)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn = train_input_fn(train, y_train, batch_size=5000))
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn = eval_input_fn(valid, y_valid))

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Comment: You should post your code so we can see if you are doing something wrong. Tensorflow should use both GPU ram and compute.

Comment: you can refer to the edit

Comment: Try to change a batch size (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159053/tensorflow-gpu-utilization-below-10)

Answer (score 2):

According to TensorFlow docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu), TensorFlow will use as much as your GPU memory by default.

Also, you can check which tensor calculation is using which device in terminal with following code:

```
# Creates an estimator with log_device_placement set to True.
sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(session_config = sess_config)
your_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(config=run_config)
```

You'll see something like this:

```
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus
id: 0000:05:00.0
b: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
a: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
MatMul: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

where `GPU:0` is your default GPU.

Comment: Well this is fine, I have no issue that it uses 100% of my GPU RAM by default, my question is why it doesn't use my GPU compute capabilities

Comment: I've edited my code since you're using tf.estimator. With the log you can check the gpu usage of TensorFlow. You can debug your programme based on the log. If everything is fine then the GPU usage is normal.

Comment: just a small question ... where gpu_options comes from in your first line below the comment ?

Comment: I did this: sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
and now I can see where each operation goes. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Cuda is a platform which allows you to run C/C++ code on the GPU. Cuda cores are part of GPU. So it is using Cuda cores for computation.

It is normal for Tensorflow to use GPU. Special operations like Matrix addition, multiplication, etc can be executed quite efficiently on a GPU as compared to a CPU (because of parallelism and hardware acceleration).

Comment: Well I am confused, if you check here https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-770m/specifications it says my GPU has 960 CUDA Cores ...