# Tensorflow GPU utilization below 10 %

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to use my gpu NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1050, with tensorflow to train a neural network. I have tried with different code examples of different neural networks and the result is always a GPU utilization of 8% with computation that are much slower than with CPU.
From this screen you can see the utilization during train.

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you observe the same thing if you change your inputs to something trivial? e.g. random noise? Obviously your network won't learn, but if GPU performance skyrockets you'll know the issue is with your input pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application.It is not unusual to have low GPU utilization.Try increasing the batch size

Comment: I have tried to change the batch size. My dataset contains 34000 examples, now using a batch size of 3600 i can reach a GPU utilization around 47 %. So in general training the model with GPU requires  a larger batch size ?

Comment: yes,then gpu will have advantage over cpu and also depends on the model that you are using,whether its sequential or can be done  in parallel like cnn.GPU are generally useful when you are working on a very large dataset with lots of features.And  how much the model is able to use parallelism.But large batch size may not be good for every tasks

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes GPU utilization is bounded by HDD speed. Especially when training data does not fit into RAM and consists of millions of images I observed that one epoch training takes exactly the same time as reading all data from disk. Changing hdd with ssd or even nvm drive proportionally increased tensorflow training speed 5x in my case.